# extjs 4 grid move the focus in a particular cell

Tags: extjs

I would like to move the focus in a particular cell, but if I insert the following code into the edit grid does not work:

```
var rowSelected2 = getWin(idWin, idGrid).view.getSelectionModel().getCurrentPosition().row;
var plugin2 = getWin(idWin, idGrid).getPlugin(idPlugin);
plugin2.startEdit(rowSelected2, 5);
```

why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set a grid cell's focus using the API, you'll need to first make sure that you have added a selection model type of cellmodel to your grid.

```
selModel: {
     selType: 'cellmodel'
}
```

After that, you can set focus by issuing the following command:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().setCurrentPosition({row: 1, column: 1});
```

Good luck!

Comment: is there a way to select the header ?